# How do generativists account for apparent diachronic processes that cause errors in linguistic performance to become cemented as competence?

Tags: historical-linguistics, generative-grammar, chomsky, language-competence

Many diachronic processes of language change appear to derive from synchronic errors in linguistic performance. How do generativists account for this if performance and competence are separate? If errors in linguistic performance are not considered part of "language," how do they cause changes in language?

Comment: Not all generativists believe every random thought that Chomsky has articulated. Only some.

Answer (score 3):

Linguistic performance *is* part of "language", in the E-language sense. Generative theory is a theory of the computational mechanism, which underlies human speech output. So the grammar say "Do X", but a speaker does not always follow those rules, or, the rules may produce an output which is under non-optimal conditions (i.e. normal conditions) indistinguishable from a different output. The grammar is induced on the basis of the ambient data (a grammar cannot be directly transmitted from mind to mind), so to the extent that the data diverges from what the grammar would compute, the language will change. This is discussed extensively in Mark Hale's *Historical Linguistics: Theory and Method*.

Comment: It seems, though, that Chomsky largely rules out linguistic performance as being part of linguistic theory: "Linguistic theory is concerned primarily with an ideal speaker-listener, in a completely homogeneous speech-community, who knows its (the speech community's) language perfectly and is unaffected by such grammatically irrelevant conditions as memory limitations, distractions, shifts of attention and interest, and errors (random or characteristic) in applying his knowledge of this language in actual performance."

Comment: Also, the process you've described seems kind of random, and yet there seem to be set patterns of linguistic change that repeat throughout history in a wide variety of language families. It seems like you need a coherent account of how I-language and E-language relate in order to explain that.

Comment: That's a quirk of Chomsky's use of "linguistic" to mean specifically "grammatical". And I would say that Hale provides that coherent account of how I-language relates to E-language at least from the historical POV. The appearance of randomness decreases once you consider how likely it is that a particular error will arise (for example, post-nasal voicing is highly likely to arise, post-nasal devoicing is unlikely to arise, but both do happen).

Comment: Re: randomness, you can describe some errors systematically, no? For example, the familiar apron/napron, ekename/nickname, un os/un nos issue is easy to formulate. It's not the most interesting error but it gives an idea.

Comment: In fact I don't know of any evidence that GG believes in true randomness. Instead, it believes that certain explanations are outside the domain of the theory of computation.

Answer (score 1):

A younger generation mistakenly takes their elders' errors to be rule-produced.  So they have to make up new rules to explain what they hear.  We wouldn't have this problem if the rules could be codified and taught.

Comment: If the elders language errors are consistent then they must be produced by *alternative rules*.  Does your 'could' mean 'would',or do you mean that we use cognitive processes that are beyond conscious comprehension?

Comment: @amI, the elder generation errors may be performance errors -- why would they be consistent with each other or with any system? That's the point here.  It is the next generations' task to rationalize the language they hear into a new system, derived from the earlier system with performance errors mixed in.

Comment: Oh -- but a spurious explanation of a random error is likely to be corrected before becoming infectious.

Comment: @aml, Oh, really? Perhaps because of the direct mind-to-mind contact that user6726 mentioned above?

Comment: We seem to be talking past each other -- My 'correction' is made by the listener, precisely because the error (if random) is inconsistent with subsequent exposure.  If the speaker's error is instead repeated (internalized by the speaker due to a misinterpreted rule), then the listener must deduce a compatible rule.  I can see lexical changes perhaps coming from single errors (since they are just data, not rules), but I think syntactic (rule) changes require repeated examples.  Can *performance* errors fit that pattern?

Comment: @amI, this is why Chomsky talks about "poverty of the stimulus".  It is clearer for syntax, perhaps, that there is not enough evidence in what they hear for children to notice counterexamples for all the bad theories they could make up about what adult competence is like.

Comment: .. but new recording and search technology allows testing of the actual 'economics of stimulus'.  Perhaps we can deduce how often the subconscious theories are revised, and how much is hard-coded.